# Converting Google spreadsheet date into a JS Date object?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been going round in circles on this one... I've got a spreadsheet which holds two dates, and I need to find the number of elapsed years between the two (ie. someone's age at a given date; this is a replacement for Excel's DATEDIF).

The first step is to convert Google's serial number into a JS Date object, but there doesn't appear to be Date constructor that does this. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the formula's in this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqhqY231XZd3cFBiY2VqeWdmNWdaZ1BqVVZ2Q1pxWVE&hl=en#gid=0

Comment: No go, I'm afraid - you can't use spreadsheet functions in apps-script, so you have to write it from scratch.

Comment: That last post in [this thread](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps-script/services/47tY3PTkExo) suggests that you can get the spreadsheet date, use some spreadsheet javascript utilities to convert it to a text format that the javascript date constructor can handle and then feed that string to the javascript date constructor.  If you get serious about Googling this problem, I suspect you will find an answer.

Answer (score 17):

To convert a Google spreadsheet date to a javascript date :

```
var JSdate = Date.parse(Cell.getValue())
```

To convert a javascript date to a Google spreadsheet date:

```
function GoogleDate( JSdate ) { 
   var D = new Date(JSdate) ;
   var Null = new Date(Date.UTC(1899,11,30,0,0,0,0)) ; // the starting value for Google
   return ((D.getTime()  - Null.getTime())/60000 - D.getTimezoneOffset()) / 1440 ;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I know you are happy with your solution as it stands, but I just wanted to add my observations of how Google Apps Script deals with "dates", either passed in a custom function, or retrieved from a cell with getValue().

My rule of thumb is that if Sheets (the spreadsheet application) is providing a value *formatted* as a date (either by automatic coercion, or the user setting the format), then Google Apps Script will automatically hold this value as a date object.

Eg:

```
function returnDate(value) {
  return new Date(value);  
}
```

If you enter `1/1/13` in A1, and in another cell you invoke `=returnDate(A1)`, it will return the same date (as it would if you simply had `return value;` in the code). However, watch what happens when you format A1 as "Normal" (convert it to a numerical value). Here, the "Sheets serial number" (number of days from 30/12/1899) is converted into a date object by Google Apps Script, but in GAS it is "regarded" as the number of milliseconds from midnight 1/1/1970. So you might get unexpected results if you are passing numerical values that you believe are representative of a date.

Also compare:

`=returnDate(DATE(2013;1;1))`

`=returnDate(VALUE("1/1/13"))`

`=returnDate(DATEVALUE("1/1/13"))`

`=returnDate("1/1/13")`

`=returnDate("1/1/2013")`

The latter two "work", because `new Date()` successfully creates the date object from a valid string, but note that Sheets automatically coerces to the current century, while GAS coerces a two-digit year to the 1900's.

So IMO if you wanted it to behave exactly as it would in Excel (that is, "regard" a numerical value as a serial number for a date), you would need to first test if the passed parameter is a date object (or "valid" text string), and if not, mathematically convert it from "days from 30/12/1899" to "milliseconds from 1/1/1970", and then `new Date()` it.

Apologies for the long-winded post.

Comment: A version of the function Adam describes is in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33813783/1677912).

Answer (score 7):

This is what I did:

```
function numberToDate(number){
  var date = new Date(number * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 70);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  return (date);
}
```

This may seem a bit dirty, but this is the only solution I found for now

Comment: I know this is not suppose to be done, but you just saved my life! :)

Answer (score 1):

After some more experimenting, it turned out that it just works, which was a bit of a surprise. `new Date(cell)` seems to internally convert the serial number into a string which is sufficient to create the date object. Full answer:

```
function datedif(first, second, format) {
  var e1  = new Date(first);
  var e2  = new Date(second);
  var age = e2.getFullYear() - e1.getFullYear();
  if(
      (e2.getMonth() <  e1.getMonth()) || 
     ((e2.getMonth() == e1.getMonth()) && (e2.getDate() < e1.getDate())))
    age--;
  return age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me

```js
private static getDateFromGoogle(serialNumber: number): Date {
  // Google     30 Dec 1899
  // Javascript 01 Jan 1970
  return new Date((serialNumber - 25569) * 86400000);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
return new Date(1900, 0, --excelDate)
```

Comment: I was trying to convert a date which was returned from the v4 API as a number. This is the answer that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to get timezone setting from google sheet config.

Then, this is the perfect solution:

```
import { zonedTimeToUtc, utcToZonedTime } from "date-fns-tz";

const SheetDate = {
  origin: Date.UTC(1899, 11, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  dayToMs: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
};
function serialToDate(d: number, sheetTimeZone: string): Date {
  return zonedTimeToUtc(
    new Date(d * SheetDate.dayToMs + SheetDate.origin),
    sheetTimeZone
  );
}
function dateToSerial(date: Date, sheetTimeZone: string) {
  const msec = utcToZonedTime(date, sheetTimeZone).getTime() - SheetDate.origin;
  return msec / SheetDate.dayToMs;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

By "serial number" I'm guessing you're talking about a unix time in seconds or milliseconds from the epoch. You can simply use the standard Javascript Date object:

```
new Date(value);
```

Google is your friend from there. Here's some references to start you off:

- [W3 Schools reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)
- [W3 Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)
- [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Javascript allows you to do simple subtraction with two Dates, returning you the time difference in ms.

```
var timeDiffInMS = date2 - date1;
```

That should be all you need to figure it out, so I'll leave the years calculation as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Google seems to store date values in the same way as Excel, as days from the last day of 1899, so Google must be doing some magic somewhere. Still, 'new Date(value)' works, so I'll mark you up... :)

Comment: Serial Number is not the same as Epoch time.