# Google Spreadsheet select column current date

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a spreadsheet in which we put out planning.
From column B till the last possible column there are dates on row A2.
I tried to write a function that places your cursor on this cell.
But I'm a little stuck and my knowledge of javascript is limited.

```
function onOpen() {
    getTodayRow();
};

function getTodayRow(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('2014a');
    var rowContent = sheet.getRange('B:A2').getValues();
    var today = new Date().getDate();
    var val = 1;
    for(var n in rowContent)
    {
        if (new Date(rowContent[n][0]).getDate() == today)
        {
            val=Number(n)+1;break
        }
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(val);
    // return val;
    // the +1 above is because arrays count from 0 and rows count from 1. (Number() is to avoid having 13+1=131 which is the default behavior unfortunately)
    sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(2, val)); //activate on right date
}
```

Is there anyone who can tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Could you share a sample spreadsheet or explain how the sheet looks like. I was not able to understand "From column B till the last possible column there are dates on row A2"

Comment: It looks like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26009685/ScreenShot035.jpg

Comment: you have the same (dates) in rows too, right? I ask because everywhere you have used `rows`

Comment: yes, but that can be changed to a unique date

Comment: so you just want the cursor to go the column with the date as part today's date. Nothing to do with the content of rows.

Comment: yes that's basically it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it and added a few more tweaks like not needing to enter the name of the sheet.
You just make the sheet you use the first in line.

```
function onOpen() {
  getTodayRow();
};

function getTodayRow(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rowContent = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; // [0] as we are using just one row i.e.
  var today = new Date();
  Logger.log(today);
  var val = 1;
  for(var n = 0; n < rowContent.length; n++) {
    var fDate = new Date(rowContent[n]);
    if (fDate.getDate() == today.getDate() && fDate.getMonth() == today.getMonth() && fDate.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear()) { // assuming its a number. If it's a formatted date you use if (new Date(rowContent[n] == today)
      val = n + 2 + 13; // + 2 because of arrays and the since the columns start from B => today
                        // + 2 + 13 to get today's date in the middle of the screen
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(val);
  sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(2, val)); //activate on right date
}
```

thx for your help Konstant!

Comment: awesome. +1 for figuring it our yourself

Answer (score 0):

Here is the edited getTodayRow function that you could use. You can modify this as per your requirement.

```
function getTodayRow(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('2014a');
  var rowContent = sheet.getRange(2, 2, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; // [0] as we are using just one row i.e.
  var today = new Date().getDate();
  var val = 1;
  for(var n = 0; n < rowContent.length; n++) {
    if (rowContent[n] == today) { // assuming its a number. If it's a formatted date you use if (new Date(rowContent[n] == today)
      val = n + 2; // + 2 because of arrays and the since the columns start from B
      break;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(val);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(val);
  // return val;
  sheet.setActiveCell(sheet.getRange(2, val)); //activate on right date
}
```

Comment: I used (new Date(rowContent[n]) == today) but it still only goes to the first column in the row. Except for that it looks pretty good though :)

Comment: my bad.. use `new Date(rowContent[n]).getDate()`. getDate function extracts the date part from the date.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Since you are new to SO, I would request you to accept the answer. It's a good practice. You can read more about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: i can't upvote :s it says i need 15 rep. i did accept it though. but i still have a small issue too :s it doesn't scan the month, the only column selected is january

Comment: Let me explain the working of `getDate`. If the date is `24-April-2014`, `getDate` will return `24`. If you have all the months and dates in the same sheet, you need to remove `getDate` for variable `today` as well as `rowContent[n]`. I assume you have all months and all dates in a single sheet. Try to log the value of variable `today` and `rowContent[n]`, you'll get there.

Comment: Did everything you said, still doens't work. I have always hated javascript -__-

Comment: did you log the values? any strange behavior?

Comment: var today = new Date();
  Logger.log(today);
  var val = 1;
  for(var n = 0; n < rowContent.length; n++) {
    if (new Date(rowContent[n]) == today) { // assuming its a number. If it's a formatted date you use if (new Date(rowContent[n] == today)
      val = n + 2; // + 2 because of arrays and the since the columns start from B
      break;
    }
  }

the selected cell is A2

Comment: This is interesting.. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363073/converting-google-spreadsheet-date-into-a-js-date-object). Basically Google Scripts date and JS Date are different and hence we are getting this. So this needs to be handled too.