# How to use duration values from Google Spreadsheet to Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, sum, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, duration

Say, I have the values `01:00`, `01:00`, `00:30`, `00:30`, `01:00`, `01:00`, `00:30`, `00:30`, `01:00` in duration format (HH:MM) in cell `E2` to `E10`.

The formula `=SUM(E2:E10)` returns `07:00` which is correct, but my following custom spreadsheet function written in Google Apps Script returns `07:54` which is incorrect.

How can I correctly calculate sum of the durations using a custom function?

```
function totalDuration() {
    var result    = 0;
    var durations = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E2:E10").getValues();

    for(var i = 0; i < durations.length; i++) {
        var date = new Date(durations[i]);
        result  += (date.getHours() * 60) + date.getMinutes();
    }

    return result / 60 / 24;
}
```

Comment: Use split js function

Comment: This describes the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363073/converting-google-spreadsheet-date-into-a-js-date-object ... You could use logging or the debugger to see the cause. Looks like the spreadsheet dates have a year of 1900 and when converted to JavaScript date, it is causing a problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [GAS: How to read the correct time values form Google Spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715841/gas-how-to-read-the-correct-time-values-form-google-spreadsheet)

Comment: Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715841/gas-how-to-read-the-correct-time-values-form-google-spreadsheet/17727300#17727300) on a similar question for sample code that simplifies this.