# How to get a date format string from a sheet cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a google script function I need to get a date value from a google sheets I have done something like this

```
var csh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var date = csh.getRange('A1').getValue();
var msg = "date = " + date;
```

What I get is something like

```
msg = "date = 42323"
```

How do I format the date variable to appear as a date

thanks

Comment: What is the format string applied to cell A1? (Try `var fmt = csh.getRange('A1').getNumberFormat();`)

Comment: The format seemed to be the issue.  I was assuming normal british date format (dd/mm/yyyy) but it was either not set or mm/dd/yyyy.  The cell in question had a date that works in the former but not the latter - 21/12/2015.  When I set the cell to the correct format everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

As jvdh said, a date in a spreadsheet should be automatically converted to a JavaScript date in Google Apps Script. There's something more to your situation that we've heard so far.

On a [related question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14367356), AdamL did a great job explaining how dates are represented. He also hinted at a way to convert from the numeric "serial number" (or "Epoch") date value in a spreadsheet to the Unix-style values used in JavaScript.

Here is my version of that utility. To use, just pass in the value read from the spreadsheet, like this:

```js
var csh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var date = convert2jsDate( csh.getRange('A1').getValue() );
var msg = "date = " + date;
```

The utility can handle existing dates, "serial numbers", or string formats that are supported by JavaScript's [dateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

```js
/**
 * Convert any spreadsheet value to a date.
 * Assumes that numbers are using Epoch (days since 1 Jan 1900, e.g. Excel, Sheets).
 * 
 * @param {object}  value  (optional) Cell value; a date, a number or a date-string 
 *                         will be converted to a JavaScript date. If missing or
 *                         an unknown type, will be treated as "today".
 *
 * @return {date}          JavaScript Date object representation of input value.
 */
function convert2jsDate( value ) {
  var jsDate = new Date();  // default to now
  if (value) {
    // If we were given a date object, use it as-is
    if (typeof value === 'date') {
      jsDate = value;
    }
    else {
      if (typeof value === 'number') {
        // Assume this is spreadsheet "serial number" date
        var daysSince01Jan1900 = value;
        var daysSince01Jan1970 = daysSince01Jan1900 - 25569 // 25569 = days TO Unix Time Reference
        var msSince01Jan1970 = daysSince01Jan1970 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // Convert to numeric unix time
        var timezoneOffsetInMs = jsDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000;
        jsDate = new Date( msSince01Jan1970 + timezoneOffsetInMs );
      }
      else if (typeof value === 'string') {
        // Hope the string is formatted as a date string
        jsDate = new Date( value );
      }
    }
  }
  return jsDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

apps script automatically converts Spreadsheet dates to Javascript dates. when I run your code, msg is equal to "date = Wed Nov 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)" for me.

If this doesn't work for you for some reasons you might want to try to use new Date(); e.g. `date = new Date(date)`;

Comment: strange. I am definitely getting a number.  If I use it to initialize a date object ( i.e dateobj = new Date(date); ) I get Thu, 1 Jan 1970 when the date should be 15 Nov 2015.  I confirmed that the cell in the spreadsheet is a date....

Comment: can you test that if you double click this cell you get a calendar  ?

Comment: I had already found the problem before I read this.  It's a shame because it would have helped a lot. I tried using isDate("A1") on the sheet and that was returning true so I though it was ok.  But when I reproduced the problem and double clicked - no calendar...