# Weird issue parsing date with Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am seeing some very strange behavior with reading a date from my sheet. Here is my code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var values = dataRange.getValues();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(values[14][9]);
```

The cell at 14,9 has the following date 10/15/2016 but when I do the alert, I get the following value - 42658

I don't understand what's going on. Can someone help me with this?

---

This is resolved by doing

```
var values = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
```

Comment: Use var values = dataRange.getDisplayValues();

Comment: @AneesHameed works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Google spreadsheet date into a JS Date object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363073/converting-google-spreadsheet-date-into-a-js-date-object)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [How to get a date format string from a sheet cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33809229/how-to-get-a-date-format-string-from-a-sheet-cell/)

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved by doing

```
var values = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you're getting is the number of milliseconds since the beginning of January 1, 1970 UTC. You can use various methods, like getFullYear(), getMonth(), getDate(), getDay(), getHours(), and getMinutes() to parse the item if that's more helpful. pOtta's suggestion will get you the text string that matches what's displayed.