# Google spreadsheets serial date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Apps Script editor and am trying to convert a Google spreadsheet serial date to a date formatted `mm/dd/yyyy`. The serial date is 42394 right now. Is there a way to convert it within my code on Google Apps Script?

Comment: May be a duplicate of [Converting Google spreadsheet date into a JS Date object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14363073/642706).

Answer (score 0):

Based from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)), use `formatDate(date, timeZone, format)` method. It formats date according to specification described in Java SE [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class.

Use this code to change the date notation:

`var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "mm/dd/yyyy");`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

## Count of days

If the number `42,394` was meant to be in year 2016 (2016-01-27), then apparently it represents the number of whole days since 1900.

[Google Apps Script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps_Script) seems to be a variant of JavaScript/[ECMAScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) 5 which I do not know. But I can show you the idea in Java, starting with the first of 1900 and adding the number of days.

## `java.time.LocalDate`

In Java 8 and later, the [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate epoch = LocalDate.of ( 1900 , Month.JANUARY , 1 );
int input = 42_394;
LocalDate localDate = epoch.plusDays ( input );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | from epoch: " + epoch + " = localDate: " + localDate );
```

> input: 42394 | from epoch: 1900-01-01 = localDate: 2016-01-27