# How to read value of fetched cell data as date google sheets API

Tags: python, date, date-formatting, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet that have dates formatted as "Jan 30" etc, but have actual date values.

[image]

I fetch the data using [python google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) like so:

```
def get_spreadsheet_sheets(service, spreadsheetId):
    spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId).execute()
    dateCell = "C15"
    for sheet in spreadsheet['sheets']:
        sheetTitle = sheet['properties']['title']
        rangeName = "%s!%s" % (sheetTitle, dateCell)
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
        values = result.get('values',[])
```

values gives me 'Jan 30', I would like to actually read it as `1/30/2017`.. How can I do that?

## update

Digger deeper into the [spreadsheets.value.get http documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) (which corresponds to the python api client method references [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.values.html#get) I learned that I can put the option of `valueRenderOption` as `UNFORMATTED_VALUE`..

however when I run that I get this weird number for `Jan 30`: `42765`

[image]

what format is that number exactly? I know it's not a unix time stamp b/c converting it returns a non-sensical date

## update 2: workaround

this code works but using python date formatting (it also assumes that the year is the current year.. but obviously that won't always be the case):

```
def get_spreadsheet_sheets(service, spreadsheetId):
    spreadsheet = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId).execute()
    dateCell = "C15"
    for sheet in spreadsheet['sheets']:
        sheetTitle = sheet['properties']['title']
        rangeName = "%s!%s" % (sheetTitle, dateCell)
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
        values = result.get('values',[])
        dateStr = "%s %s" % (values[0][0], datetime.date.today().year)
        cellDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%b %d %Y')
        print(cellDate)
```

Comment: the value python API fetches is what you see on the spreadsheet not the underlying value you input i.e. the format matters.

Comment: but how can i know the year of the date when i fetch it if i simply get `Jan 30`?

Comment: The simplest way would be changing the format of the date.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "weird number" it's called "serialized date-time value" or "date serial value". The 0 value displayed as date (yyyy-mm-dd) is  `1899-12-30`. Integers are days, fractions are hours, minutes, etc.

Related: [Converting Google spreadsheet date into a JS Date object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363073/)

References:

- [TO_DATE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094239?hl=en), Google Spreadsheet built-in function
- <s>[DateTime Serial Numbers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#datetime_serial_numbers), Article section from Google Sheets > API v4 Guide</s> (the referred section was removed, it might be available on archive.org)
- [Date and Number Formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats?hl=en), Article from Google Sheets > API v4 Guide.
- [Google Sheet API V4(Java) append Date in cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986171/) , Stack Overflow Q&A

h/t [Sam Berlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6356522/sam-berlin)

Comment: See also: [DateTime Serial Numbers](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#datetime_serial_numbers), and [Google Sheet API V4(Java) append Date in cells](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986171/google-sheet-api-v4java-append-date-in-cells/37993497#37993497).

Comment: @SamBerlin: Thank you very much.

Comment: Upvoted for the link to the Google Sheets > API v4 Guide. For whatever reason, this was very hard to find, not being in a section of its own.