# Convert Google Sheet date serial value into human readable date

Tags: python, date, google-sheets, date-conversion

**Set-up**

I'm reading a Google Sheet in Python through Google Drive API.

I've got a value for a date – a date serial value, which I need to convert into a human readable date.

I have:

```
date = 42747
```

I know that this implies that the date is `12-1-2017`.

---

**Question**

Is there an easy way to convert `42747`  to `12-1-2017`?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216491/how-to-read-value-of-fetched-cell-data-as-date-google-sheets-api), but it's not answering mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work:

```
import datetime
def convert_xls_datetime(xls_date):
    return (datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
            + datetime.timedelta(days=xls_date))

print(convert_xls_datetime(42747))
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. It actually gives me `2017-01-12 00:00:00`, is there a way to prevent it from giving a time indication, i.e. just `2017-01-12`?

Comment: `convert_xls_datetime(42747).date()` will give you just the date.

Answer (score 0):

This lists separate functions for `date` and `datetime`.

```py
import datetime
from typing import Union

_BASE_DATE = datetime.date(1899, 12, 30)
_BASE_DATETIME = datetime.datetime(_BASE_DATE.year, _BASE_DATE.month, _BASE_DATE.day)

def convert_date_from_gsheet(num_days: int, /) -> datetime.date:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66738817/
    assert isinstance(num_days, int)
    return _BASE_GSHEET_DATE + datetime.timedelta(num_days)


def convert_date_to_gsheet(date: datetime.date, /) -> int:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66738817/
    assert isinstance(date, datetime.date)
    return (date - _BASE_GSHEET_DATE).days

def convert_datetime_to_gsheet(dt: datetime.datetime, /) -> float:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66738817/
    assert isinstance(dt, datetime.datetime)
    delta = dt - _BASE_GSHEET_DATETIME
    return delta.days + delta.seconds / 86_400.0  # Note: datetime.timedelta(days=1).total_seconds() == 86_400.0

def convert_datetime_from_gsheet(num_days: Union[float, int], /) -> datetime.datetime:
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66738817/
    assert isinstance(num_days, (float, int))
    return _BASE_GSHEET_DATETIME + datetime.timedelta(num_days)
```