# how to change date format where the source contain multiple format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

How to change format date from 12-Mar-2022 to , format='%d/%m/%Y' in python

so the problem is I read data from the google sheet where in the data contain multiple format, some of them is 12/03/2022 and some of them 12-Mar-2022.

I tried using this got error of couse because doesn't match for 12-Mar-2022
defectData_x['date'] = pd.to_datetime(defectData_x['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

Appreciate your help

Comment: Did you just try `pd.to_datetime(defectData_x['date'])` without `format` to let Pandas guess the right format?

Comment: Can you update your import process to pull the date unformatted from your google sheet? That would solve any formatting issues. See similar example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216491/how-to-read-value-of-fetched-cell-data-as-date-google-sheets-api

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
defectData_x['date1'] = defectData_x['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

don forget **date1**'s dtype is not datetime but object

so it is better using **date** column and **date1** column both before make final result

after final result, you can drop **date** column

add my example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["12/03/2022", "12-Mar-2022"], columns=["date"])
df["date1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
df['date2'] = df['date1'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: still error, because they still found format 8 Mar 2022, so its not match with this format  '%d/%m/%Y'

error says:
ValueError: time data '8-Mar-2022' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)

Comment: aha. now im understanding your question. 8-Mar-2022 is "%d-%b%-%Y " format. sorry for my poor english.

Comment: now add my example for you. my english is poor, but my mind for you is not poor. if still im misunderstanding problem,  please tell me problem 1 more.

Comment: How if in the same dataframe contain multiple format?

Comment: i add my example for you. example have multiple format.